# How can I change the character of a string one by one?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I want to change all the characters in string one by one according to the substitution rule and save them to file on Linux.

This is substitution file (sub.txt).

```
A -> Y
B -> V
C -> Q
...
```

Input file:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

first, (A to Y) `YBCDEFGHIJ` -> save file

second, (B to V) `AVCDEFGHIJ` -> save file

Which method should I do?

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific in your question please? You will change all the characters (for example all As) or you will change only the first concurrency? You will make the change following any "pattern"? Initially, without additional data, I would recommend using the "sed" command; For example: sed -i 's/A/Y/g' file

Comment: i hope after the second edit, your file content should be like, `YBCDEFGHIJ `. Or do you want to save the changes in two different files?

Comment: @Dasel I edited the question. I want to change all the characters of string sequentially, and save them as a file. For example, if the string consists of 11 characters, 11 converted files are created.

Comment: @user2905046 Would the input `AA` give `YA` then `YY` or would it jump straight to `YY`?

Answer (score 4):

Given a `sub.txt` like this:

```bsh
$ cat sub.txt 
A -> Y
B -> V
C -> Q
D -> K
E -> L
F -> O
G -> P
H -> W
I -> X
J -> Z
```

You can iterate over it in a shell loop, reading each of the three elements on each line into a variable:

```bsh
while IFS=' ' read -r from ignore to; do ... ; done < sub.txt
```

In that `while` loop, the `$from` will be the source character and the `$to` will be the character you want to replace that with. The `$ignore` in the middle is just a holder for the `->`.

This assumes that space and line feed (`' '` and `\n`) are not in the list of characters you want to transliterate.

With that in mind, you can use `tr` to make the change and redirect output to a new file:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r from discard to; do 
    printf '%s\n' "$string" | tr "$from" "$to" > changed."$from".txt
done < sub.txt
```

Note that some `tr` implementations will fail if `$from` or `$to` is `[` or  if they are multi-byte characters. The above also assumes `$from` is not `/`.

If `string="ABCDEFGHIJ"`, the command above will create these files:

```
$ ls changed*
changed.A.txt  changed.D.txt  changed.G.txt  changed.J.txt
changed.B.txt  changed.E.txt  changed.H.txt
changed.C.txt  changed.F.txt  changed.I.txt
```

With the following contents:

```
$ for f in changed.*; do printf '%s\n' "=== $f ==="; cat "$f"; done
=== changed.A.txt ===
YBCDEFGHIJ
=== changed.B.txt ===
AVCDEFGHIJ
=== changed.C.txt ===
ABQDEFGHIJ
=== changed.D.txt ===
ABCKEFGHIJ
=== changed.E.txt ===
ABCDLFGHIJ
=== changed.F.txt ===
ABCDEOGHIJ
=== changed.G.txt ===
ABCDEFPHIJ
=== changed.H.txt ===
ABCDEFGWIJ
=== changed.I.txt ===
ABCDEFGHXJ
=== changed.J.txt ===
ABCDEFGHIZ
```

That changes each character separately. If you instead want to do this incrementally, so the 1st file will only have the 1st character changed, but the second file will have both the 1st and the 2nd characters changed, you can do:

```
tmpFile=$(mktemp) 
printf '%s\n' "$string" > "$tmpFile" 
while IFS=' ' read -r from ignore to; do 
    tr "$from" "$to" < "$tmpFile" > changed."$from".txt
    cp changed."$from".txt "$tmpFile"
done < sub.txt
```

This will create the following files:

```
$ for f in changed.*; do printf '%s\n' "=== $f ==="; cat "$f"; done
=== changed.A.txt ===
YBCDEFGHIJ
=== changed.B.txt ===
YVCDEFGHIJ
=== changed.C.txt ===
YVQDEFGHIJ
=== changed.D.txt ===
YVQKEFGHIJ
=== changed.E.txt ===
YVQKLFGHIJ
=== changed.F.txt ===
YVQKLOGHIJ
=== changed.G.txt ===
YVQKLOPHIJ
=== changed.H.txt ===
YVQKLOPWIJ
=== changed.I.txt ===
YVQKLOPWXJ
=== changed.J.txt ===
YVQKLOPWXZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed :

To change two characters one by one in a string,

```
sed -i 's/A/Y/;s/B/V/' file
```

To change and save in different files:

```
sed 's/A/Y/' file > file1; sed 's/B/V/' file > file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by below method and it worked fine

```
    awk '{gsub("A","Y",$0);print $0}' l.txt > f_1.txt
    awk '{gsub("B","V",$0);print $0}' l.txt > f_2.txt
    awk '{gsub("C","Q",$0);print $0}' l.txt > f_3.txt
```

Comment: I believe you've missed the part where they want the individual edits to be saved into individual files -- and not with all the changes in one file.

Comment: Corrected the code

Comment: That's in the right direction; do note that they mention having a substitution file where the ellipsis indicates that there are additional translations...

Answer (score 0):

We will do this by making `sed` work on the sub.txt file to generate a `sed` code that'll operate on the input to get the various output files, as shown here:

```
$ sed -ne '
   1i\
h
   s|\(.\)[[:blank:]*->[[:blank:]]*\(.\)|g;s/\1/\2/gw ./converted.\1_\2.txt|p
' ./sub.txt | sed -nf - ./input.file
```

We obtain the output files named as `converted.A_Y.txt`, `converted.B_V.txt`, etc.
The first `sed` invocation generates the `sed` code on the fly based on what transformations are mentioned in the sub.txt input and uses that to run the second `sed` invocation on the input data.

Assuming the sub.txt file has single character to single character transliteration and the characters are not regex to sed on either the RHS or LHS of `s///` command of `sed`.

Comment: sed -ne '1i\hs|\(.\)[[:blank:]*->[[:blank:]]*\(.\)|g;s/\1/\2/gw ./converted.\1_\2.txt|p
' ./sub.txt | sed -nf - ./input.file 
Is this correct if the code is in one line?

Comment: No that is not correct. Instead you could do this: `sed -ne '1i\h' -e 's|\(.\)[[:blank:]*->[[:blank:]]*\(.\)|g;s/\1/\2/gw ./converted.\1_\2.txt|p' ./sub.txt | sed -nf - ./inp` and that too only if you access to `GNU sed`. The `POSIX sed` will require an escaped newline like shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made script based on userinput so mistakes can be avoided

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "enter the character need to display"
    read old
    echo "enter the  need character to be replaced"
    read new
    sed "s/$old/$new/g" r.txt>file_$old.txt



First it will ask for old content which need to be replaced. 
Second it will ask for new content which needs to be replaced with old content
THird it saves the file  after each iteration

Based on how  characters need to be replaced you can add above mentioned script in for loop
```